# Datastax OpsCenter gives error message when adding analytics nodes

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to add two Spark analytics nodes to my cassandra cluster, and I keep getting the error message:

`"Error provisioning cluster: Must pass node_type_counts when adding to a vnode cluster."`

I am using DSE 4.6.4 and OpsCenter 5.1.1. The 3 nodes in my Cassandra DC use vnodes, and I am trying to use vnodes in the analytics cluster as well, by setting num_tokens in the config to 256. Is this a bug in OpsCenter? Seems like the `node_type_counts` param might be missing from the post request that OpsCenter creates. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My solution will most likely involve using the OpsCenter API directly...http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/api/docs/index.html

Comment: Solved it by reconstructing the POST request with the correct param.

Comment: Hi, what version of OpsCenter are you running? I believe this was fixed in 5.0